# nuget package , can't install EntityFrameworkCore.sqlserver

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-core, nuget-package

Hi I can't install `microsoft.entitiyFrameWorkCore.sqlserver` via `NuGet` package in

> VS 2019. I am getting this error  The feed 'nuget.org
> [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json]' lists package
> 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.2.0.1' but multiple attempts to download the
> nupkg have failed. The feed is either invalid or required packages
> were removed while the current operation was in progress. Verify the
> package exists on the feed and try again.   Unable to find package
> 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.2.0.1'.

PS : my VS version isn't the latest one

Comment: There is no package `microsoft.entitiyFrameWork.sqlserver`.

Comment: oh sorry , entityFrameWorkCore.sqlserver*

Answer (score 0):

It looks it was becaues the very bad internet connection I have , since when I connected to 4g it installed successfully